# Cross domain POST query using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing getting no data back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cors

I'm sending data cross domain via a POST request but the response isn't working, specifically, jQuery's success handler never gets called.

Stuff being used: Django, Apache, jQuery.

So, I set up a request rather similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://somesite.com/someplace",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { ... },
    success: function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
    },
});
```

As you well know, [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) allows me to respond to an `OPTIONS` query appropriately to say "Yes, you can POST to me". Which I'm doing. Firebug confirms I'm getting my `200` status code and that the return type is in fact `application/json`. However, Firebug also confirms that the success handler in the above is *not* being called.

For reference, my response to `OPTIONS` is:

```
elif request.method == "OPTIONS":
    response = HttpResponse("")
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "X-Requested-With"
    return response
```

In contrast, if I set up a `complete: function()...` handler it works.

So, question is: what's happening (or not) and why? I am getting data fine, I'd just like to be able to return the response.

---

**Update**: *This fixes my issue on some browsers but since I don't have a complete definite explanation to this behaviour I'm leaving it open*.

Ok, so I read [the manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) and what I understand of it, the algorithm applied is roughly this:

1. User agents may implement a preflight call. This is the `OPTIONS` request. The idea is that they make this request which gives them an answer with respect to the requested resource, which they are then supposed to cache. **I'm not passing back a max-age** field, so I suspect whilst success is being returned and the X-request allowed, there is nothing in the user agent's cache which permitted me to make it, so the default rules (isolate the request) are applied.
2. When you make the actual request, I believe the user agent is supposed to inspect the pre-flight cache for permissions. Without my max-age field, I believe it isn't finding these permissions. However, responding with the same headers on `POST` appears to allow Firefox and Google Chrome to view the response. Opera can not. IE remains untested at the moment.

I do not currently understand and it is not clear from the manual (to me at least) whether a CORS request should also answer with these headers in the request as well as the `OPTIONS`. I shall experiment with the `Max-Age` header and see what that allows or does not allow. However, I'm still short of some definite authoritative understanding on the issue so if there is someone on here who knows, I'm all ears.

Comment: Chances are it's being limited due to being a cross-domain call. I wouldn't want to log on to mybank.com and have my info sent to somebank.com (Same premise applies here, no matter how trivial the payload).

Comment: The info has already been sent. CORS enables that. So whatever info that was supposed to be protected has just been POSTED to a totally separate domain and is now sat in my Postgres server. Too late. The problem here is not **sending** information, it is **receiving** it.

Comment: the browser not support this. the data is received , but the browser not let you see. you can test with "fiddler"

Comment: @Ninefingers: I was using send as an example, but the issue still remains cross-domain related. My apologies if I was too vague.

Comment: Not sure, but it might be that you need to use jsonp instead of json.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JSONToJSONP.aspx

Comment: Everyone, the idea behind CORS is that it replaces the need for JSONP and allows you both send and receive data cross domain in a safe manner. In my example, I'm able to send and not receive, which is why I'm asking. This technique is only available on modern browsers, given, but it should work in its entirety, not in half. I've managed to make that happen but I'm not sure if my interpretation of the protocol is correct, so I've updated my question. But browsers do support this and I'm deliberately NOT using JSONP.

Comment: Note that CORS only has **partial support on IE9** (_while other browsers have had full support for over 7 years now!_).  In particular, you have to use MS's **XDomainRequest** object (and it doesn't support setting headers, so POSTing url-encoded form data is out).  **jQuery doesn't even try supporting IE9 via XDomainRequest and just gives an error**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, so I believe the correct way to do things is this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data),mimetype='application/json')
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    return response
elif request.method == "OPTIONS":
    response = HttpResponse("")
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "POST, OPTIONS"
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "X-Requested-With"
    response['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1800"
else:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

This is based on the [documentation I dug up from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests) on preflighted requests.

So, what I believe will happen is this:

1. If there's nothing in the preflight cache, `OPTIONS` is sent with `X-Requested-With` set to `XMLHttpRequest` I believe this is necessary to allow Javascript access to anything, along with an `Origin` header.
2. The server can examine that information. *That is the security of CORS*. In my case, I'm responding with "any origin will do" and "you're allowed to send the `X-Requested-With` thing". I'm saying that `OPTIONS` and `POST` are allowed and that this response should be cached for 30 mins.
3. The client then goes ahead and makes the POST, which was working before.
4. I modified the response originally to include `Allow-Methods` and `Allow-Headers` but according to the exchange in the above linked documentation this isn't needed. This makes sense, the access check has already been done.
5. I believe then that what happens is the [resource sharing check described here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-sharing-check). Basically, once said request has been made, the browser again checks the `Allow-Origin` field for validity, this being on the request such as `POST`. If this passes, the client can have access to the data, if not, the request has already completed but the browser denies the actual client side application (Javascript) access to that data.

I believe that is a correct summary of what is going on and in any case it appears to work. If I'm not right, please shout.

Comment: Are you sure that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` is a legitimate response from a server? My understanding is that a server may accept any origin, but it should respond to each request with the client's Origin header...

Comment: It is valid, yes - but please note that if you are passing xhr credentials, a wild-card origin acceptance will fail, regardless.

Comment: `Access-Control-Max-Age: 180`  = 3 minutes, not 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

For any future searchers who may come across this posting, the following resource is the W3C 2008 working-draft which discusses CORS in-depth.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/

As of the time of this posting, it should be noted that Chromium specifically, and probably all of WebKit has a bug which prevents the `Access-Control-Max-Age` header's value from being honored. Details on this can be found on the discussion page for [Chromium Issue 131368](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131368). In summary - as of now, WebKit-based browsers will override whatever the server returns as a value here with `600` (10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8079/students/add/",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(somejson),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var resp = JSON.parse(response)
                alert(resp.status);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

RESPONSE:

```
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps('{"status" : "success"}'))
response.__setitem__("Content-type", "application/json")
response.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

return response
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is possible for security reasons. The only cross domain ajax calls which browsers allow, can be done using JSONP and these are exclusively GET requests.

This will work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://somesite.com/someplace",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSONP",
    data: { ... },
    success: function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
    },
});
```

This won't:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://somesite.com/someplace",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSONP",
    data: { ... },
    success: function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
    },
});
```

Comment: -1 because "The only cross domain ajax calls which browsers allow, can be done using JSONP" isn't true. I've already managed a cross domain ajax call, or half of it, as is evident when I say "getting no data back". I'm well aware of the JSONP mechanism; I'm not familiar enough with the ins and outs of CORS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) which is what I'm using here.