# jQuery cross domain image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Ok, so basically.
I inject some javascript code into a web page and it uploads an image on that page to another server.
Now I have it working when I run it on my domain (of course), but I need to post the multipart/form-data request to a PHP file that I do not own.
Since it is a upload and not a simple request to just get data, I cannot use jsonp in the initial call since the response would not be in json.

Using James Padolsey's cross domain script, I am able to do $.get and $.post request across domains, but since I am using $.ajax it does not work.
[He uses the Yahoo Query Language to acomplish this](http://pastebin.com/HMxUxqBp)

This is basically how I am making the request

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://website.com/upload.php',
type: 'POST',
contentType:'multipart/form-data',
data: postData,
success: successCallback,
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Error');
}
});
```

I want to make it completely JavaScript based to avoid making my server do the request.
So to re-cap, I can get the image bytes and make the request with javascript. But so far I cannot make it cross domain since I am $.ajax to set the content Type to "multipart/form-data".
Is there another way to make the request cross domain with or without the YQL?

Making the request with an iframe will not work since the domain of the iframe would change and I would not have access to the response.

Comment: You could proxy your request to the other server through your own domain to avoid cross domain issues.  Basically access the other domain on the server side and return the response

Comment: I mentioned that I do not want to use my server resources since it could use hundreds of requests a day.

Comment: do you absolutely NEED to access the response?

Comment: Yes, because it the return data has stats about the uploaded image that I need.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well known and difficult problem for web development, know as the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

> Javascript prevents access to most methods and properties to pages across different origins. The term "origin" is defined using the domain name, application layer protocol, and (in most browsers) port number of the HTML document running the script. Two resources are considered to be of the same origin if and only if all these values are exactly the same.

There are several ways around this.

1. [Create your own proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

   - Create a page that simply forwards the request to the other server, and returns its response
   - or, Use Apache's rules to form a proxy (see above link)
2. Use someone else's proxy

   - For GET requests which are typical [Use YQL to access yahoo's proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)
   - For POST requests, if the 3rd party supports [Open Data Tables](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-iud-statements.html)
   - or, Use some other public proxy
3. See if the 3rd party conforms to the [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) specification

   - [Cross domain POST query using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing getting no data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251689/cross-domain-post-query-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing-getting-no-data-back)
4. If you are willing to allow a little flash on your page, try [flXHR](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy#Flash-enabled_XHR)

   - it claims to implement the exact XHR api and also has a [jquery plugin](http://flxhr.flensed.com/jquery.php)

These are pretty much your only options