# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin despite correct headers

Tags: javascript, http-headers, cross-domain, xss, cors

I am trying to set up simple Cross-Origin Resource Sharing using jQuery (1.7.1) powered ajax on the client and apache served python (django) server.  According to all the instructions I have read my headers are set correctly, but I keep getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myexternaldomain.com/get_data.
>   Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The header being I am trying to (I am not sure it is even getting past the browser) send is:

```
Request URL:http://myexternaldomain.com/get_data
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/static/js/test-zetta.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11
```

The javascript code is

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        url : "http://myexternaldomain.com/get_data",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        crossDomain : true
    });
```

Note that `origin` is set correctly.  The server adds the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *` using the following python code

```
def process_response(self, response):
    if response.has_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'):
            return response

    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response

def get_orders(request):
    """ Tell worker what to do """
    response_data = {}
    response_data['action'] = 'probe'
    response = process_response(HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype="application/json"))
    return response
```

If I visit the address directly, it appears to confirm that the header is being set correctly

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 08 Mar 2012 05:06:25 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

However in the cross domain setting it always fails (tried both chrome and firefox).  I've tried implementing the code exactly as per the selected answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251689/cross-domain-post-query-using-cross-origin-resource-sharing-getting-no-data-back) question, but get the same error

**Update**

I am quite sure that the problem is server side, as I have managed to get my ajax calls working with a different public CORS enabled server.  When I compare the headers coming back from this public server, and the ones returned from mine (when I test from same domain), I cannot see any major difference which could account for difference (see below).

One subtlety that I excluded, which may or may be important is that the actual domain is an amazon domain of multiple subdomains.  The **real address** is http://ec2-23-20-27-108.compute-1.amazonaws.com/get_orders , feel free to probe it to see what I am doing wrong.

**From Public server**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:622
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 08 Mar 2012 15:33:20 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Perl/5.8.7, PHP/4.4.0
```

**From my server - (not working cross domain)**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Thu, 08 Mar 2012 15:32:24 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: I've tried, in the past, enabling CORS for Json data and never been successful. CORS can be flaky like that. You'd be much better off just returning JSON-P.

Comment: You're only posting the headers from the _final_ exchange between your remote server and local client. If you look at the complete exchange, I'm sure you will see an OPTIONS request along with a response that contains Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I was being mislead by the response from going to the URL, and in fact the problem was that when doing the ajax request, I was getting a 403 (only revealed in firefox not chrome) error due to csrf protection.

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much. I had my `enable_cors` wrapper around my `csrf_exempt` wrapper, needed to reverse them. I was like, WTF...

Answer (score 5):

You have to implement a "pre-flighted" request and response because your situation counts as a "[not so simple](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)" request. Basic CORS, that only requires the Origin header, can only have content types of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data", and "text/plain". Since you return "application/json", you don't meet this requirement.

I don't know anything about Django, but I found it easier to implement CORS support outside of my application through the use of a [Tomcat filter](https://bitbucket.org/jsumners/corsfilter). It looks like you can [do the same thing](https://github.com/elevenbasetwo/django-cors) with Django.

**2013-08-11:** It looks like the GitHub repo is no longer with us. But the Django package looks to still be available at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cors/0.1

Comment: Pretty sure the browser is supposed to take care of the preflight request....at least Chrome does.

Comment: But the server has to recognize it. His script only responds to basic requests by adding the Origin header to every request.

Comment: I tried making the request simple, by making my data a simple string, expecting plain text in the $.ajax call and returning mimetype='text/plain' in the python, but still get the same errors.

Comment: I've also managed to make it work with a public cors enabled server, so can be pretty confident in that my problem is server side.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was saying. Your server side script is not handling the pre-flight type of requests. Based on the code you have provided, your script will only work with basic CORS requests.

Comment: Further, if you return the string '{"foo":"bar"}' to jQuery as "text/plain", it might fail because it recognizes the string as JSON. I'm not sure about that one, though.

Comment: I can't overstate the awesomeness of this answer. It's dead-on.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the excellent [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) library and ran into this problem as well. For me, the solution was to add 'accept-encoding' to the default CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS tuple.