# CORS Header Error when using Authorization Header

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

So this is my current code
[image]

When I delete the `Authorization` from the `headers` the request will be successful, and i get the response. But when I use the `Authorization` header, it will give me this error.

[image]

The server is using `Python Django` and using [this libary](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) for CORS Handling

**EDIT 1: This is the `python` server settings**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2: Add Browser**

I use Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit)

**EDIT 3: Postman response**

Just got weird response here. When the backend guy tried from his laptop, he got the complete header. like this:
[image]
But when i use my laptop, i got this response:
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of your  `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @r3ign already tried to `ALLOW_ALL` so the `WHITELIST` is ignored

Comment: I'm thinking that `Authorization` is not added in `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`

Comment: Also, it is weird that the request is successful when there is no Authorization header. Anything that might cause this in your code?

Comment: Can you please give complete details of *all* relevant entries in `settings.py` and also what browser you were using when this error occurred? If not, this will eventually be a guessing game. Also, browser information helps as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9627028/3602025)

Comment: Are you by any chance using cookies or csrf tokens even though you are using Token Auth?

Comment: @r3ign nope, the backend guy said that he didn't even install csrf, and i use localstorage instead of cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
It's caused by the App Enlight plugin for monitoring. When I remove it, everything works without errors :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing cors is not allowing the `Authorization` header. So, lets add that the `Authorization` entry to `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
...
'Authorization',
...
)
```

Comment: sadly, it's also already added. When i tried using postman, this is the headers of the response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

Comment: Are you sure that headers are not *case-sensitive*?

Comment: My bad headers are case-insensitive according [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#appendix-A.2)

Comment: Have you added the `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` under `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?

Comment: And also, add `corsheaders` in INSTALLED_APPS ?